# How can I save only unique models in Spring Data?

Tags: spring, exception, spring-data

I try to fix exception: `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint`  when save model with help repository.save(model).

How will I fix this exception?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save or update something but it's forbidden by an unique constraint.

Two cases :

1. You are trying to INSERT a new record with the same unique field, change it choosing the next value for the primary key or another value for the unique field.
2. You are trying to INSERT but you should make an UPDATE for updating the same record.

[EDIT] You have said it's the 2sd case in comments. So you should retrieve the record from database firstly, and then you can update it changing some fields, and persist it again as you have done.

Comment: Second case is matched

Comment: So you should retrieve the record from database firstly, and then you can update it changing some fields, and persist it again as you have done.